# Get variable from Post Data (PHP)

Tags: php, variables, post

I really don't know why my code isn't working! Let me clear it by example..

I got a file named 'index.html' example...

```
<html>
      <body>
            <form action="test.php" method="post">
                       Name: <input type="text" name="test">
                      <input type="submit">
             </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

And of course the form action file test.php .. example..

```
<?php

$something = ($_POST["test"]);

// from here I have some  PHP codes and this "something" variable will be process in this codes and will print out something spacial..
?>
```

Now example If I post "Hello, It's not working" then the output will show a spacial design.
But Instead process, it's just printing out whatever I submit in that form.
But when I manually add the variable to "something" and if I execute the "test.php" . Example..

```
$something = "Hello, It's not working";
```

Then it works perfectly..

And yes. Also tried GET method.. It's still same as POST.
This is my first question here..
Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Comment: "Now example If I post "Hello, It's not working" then the output will show a spacial design" <- huh, what? :) Please reformulate.

Comment: I mean It will print something spacial.. Example, that "Hello, It's not working" will show a output with some BBcodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
First Convert, index.html to php and follow this code:-

<html>
      <body>
            <form action="test.php" method="post">
                       Name: <input type="text" value="" name="test">
                      <input name="submit" value="submit" type="submit">
             </form>
     </body>
</html>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $something = $_POST["test"];
}

?>
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/q1slws Here is the index.php and here is that test,php http://prntscr.com/q1smp4 .. That doesn't work... Same same output as before.. @anil-kum

Answer (score 0):

That's correct _POST:

```
<?php
//NO  ($_POST["test"])
$something = $_POST["test"];

?>
```

Comment: Prentheses are superfluous, but they don't make a difference here.

Comment: he said the function doesnt work without set it manually, so the problem is on variable. If he try with my code im sure the function work fine.

Comment: `$a = ($b);` is the exact equivalent of `$a = $b;`.